# Open source Rails/Sinatra/Ruby web mail client?

Tags: gmail, email, open-source

Is anyone aware of any? I'm specifically looking for any that are well maintained (in the Ruby community that generally means the source is availble on GitHub).  Here's what I've found in my research:

#### MailCatcher

MailCatcher runs a super simple SMTP server which catches any message sent to it to display in a web interface.

- [official site](http://mailcatcher.me)
- [source code](http://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher)

#### Sup

Sup is a console-based email client for people with a lot of email. It supports tagging, very fast full-text search, automatic contact- list management, custom code insertion via a hook system, and more. If you're the type of person who treats email as an extension of your long-term memory, Sup is for you.

- [official site](http://sup.rubyforge.org/)
- [source code](http://gitorious.org/projects/sup)

#### ActionMailer

- [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actionmailer)

Comment: Are you looking for a [webmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webmail) app (i.e. SquirrelMail and other web-based e-mail clients) or a ruby email/smtp library (i.e. ActionMailer) or just any e-mail-related ruby apps (e.g. Sup, Mailcatcher, etc.)?

Comment: web-based.  As I researched more and didn't find what I wanted, I started looking at gems, etc.

Comment: What's your goal here? This sounds like you are developing your own application, as such you are not a "user" as defined by this site.

Answer (score 1):

Your are probably looking for something like the [LamsonProject](http://lamsonproject.org/); a modern framework for writing email applications in Python, created by the prolific Zed Shaw.

I am not aware of a Ruby based equivalent. See: http://lamsonproject.org/docs/faq.html